# mysqlimport using dump

Tags: mysql

I need to restore a dumped database, but without discarding existing rows in tables.

To dump I use:

```
mysqldump -u root --password --databases mydatabase > C:\mydatabase.sql
```

To restore I do *not* use the mysql command, since it will discard all existing rows, but instead mysqlimport should do the trick, obviously. But how? Running:

```
mysqlimport -u root -p mydatabase c:\mydatabase.sql
```

says "table mydatabase.mydatabase does not exist". Why does it look for tables? How to restore dump with entire database without discarding existing rows in existing tables? I could dump single tables if mysqlimport wants it.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are concerned with stomping over existing rows, you need to mysqldump it as follows:

```
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--no-create-info --skip-extended-insert"
mysqldump -uroot --ppassword ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --databases mydatabase > C:\mydatabase.sql
```

This will do the following:

- remove `CREATE TABLE` statements and use only INSERTs.
- It will INSERT exactly one row at a time. This helps mitigate rows with duplicate keys

With the mysqldump performed in this manner, now you can import like this

```
mysql -uroot -p --force -Dtargetdb < c:\mydatabase.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!

**WARNING** : Dumping with `--skip-extended-insert` will make the mysqldump really big, but at least you can control each duplicate done one by one. This will also increase the length of time the reload of the mysqldump is done.

Answer (score 1):

I would edit the mydatabase.sql file in a text editor, dropping the lines that reference dropping tables or deleting rows, then manually import the file normally using the `mysql` command as normal.

```
mysql -u username -p databasename < mydatabase.sql
```

The [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) command is designed for dumps created with the mysql command `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` rather than direct database dumps.

Comment: Yes, and things to leave out can be done automatically using given commands in reply below. Convenient when table count is huge :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is much more complicated than you are describing.

If you do a backup the way you describe, it has all the records in your database. Then you say that you do not want to delete existing rows from your database and load from the backup? Why? The reason why the backup file (the output from mysqldump) has the drop and create table commands is to ensure that you don't wind up with two copies of your data.

The right answer is to load the mysqldump output file using the mysql client. If you don't want to do that, you'll have to explain why to get a better answer.